# Hide a password from one self

Tags: android, passwords, key

I'm developing an Android APP to control a food safe which should be closed e.g. for 20hours. As I want to use it myself I want that the App creates a random password and stores it in the controller of the safe (Bluetooth + Arduino) and in the App. The safe only accepts commands from the phone if the password is correct.

How can I hide the password in the APP from myself?

I tryed to store the random  password in the encrypted shared preferences, but I just need to connect my phone to my PC and run the APP and then I can debug the password (though it is a released non debuggable version).

Any advice would be so great. Thanks

Answer (score -2):

I'm not sure about what's the issue you're facing.

About hiding the password from yourself the best way I found so far is saving the MD5 equivalent in a file/DB.

To login instead of doing `(TextBoxPassword == Password)` you will call a function: `(GetMd5(TextBoxPassword) == Password)`, where the stored password is **already an MD5 hash**.

Comment: Note that MD5 is extremely insecure nowadays because it's been broken many times.